# Can we use pin 3 and 5 for rtc clock module and for detecting input from push button while both are connected?

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, i2c

I have my project where all the GPIO pins of raspberry pi have been utilized. Now I want to add an rtc clock module to the RaspberryPi. Pin 3 and 5 are already connected to the push button in input mode.

The raspberry pi needs to update the time only on startup and detecting push-button will be carried later on. So the question is how can I achieve this i.e using the pin first in i2c and then in GPIO mode?

Comment: You need to explain how pins 3 and 5 are currently wired to the push button(s).

Comment: @joan They are wired in input mode.

Comment: That does not help.  Please provide a wiring diagram showing how the GPIO are connected to the buttons and how the buttons are connected to the Pi.

Comment: Ah, Pins 3, 5 are almost always, or usually used for I2C, or not so usually for SPI. So it is a bad idea to use those pins. You may like to pick other pins: https://imgur.com/PSwTXaK.  Happy pin picking. Cheers.